# How to use git branches and local directories to completely rewrite a file?

Tags: git

I think I still have not fully understand how `git` works.

Say, I have an `index.html` in my local directory `home` which also holds my local git repository.

I constantly push my commit to a remote repository.

Right now there is only a local and remote branch `master`.

I intend to completely rewrite the local file `index.html` - and with it probably the attached `css` and `js` files.

If I understand rightly, I should create a new branch first - let's call it `rework`. But what does it mean for my local file? When I edit the html file and save it it's locally gone. I will commit the new file to `rework`. But what if I am not sure which of the two versions I will finally keep? How can I get my old version from master physically back on my drive?

And to to make it even more complex, what if I had two versions of the same website, that I am working on. One I would commit to the branch `rework-1` and the other to `rework-2`. But how would I organize my local directories? Create several folders?

Comment: Seems like you could use a good reference: http://git-scm.com/book and particularly the section on branching http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching.

Comment: I think you're a little confused - if you have committed a file at least once, even if you erase all file contents you'll still have the last version where your file had contents. See [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git actually creates a virtual filesystem of its own. You should forget to think in files and folders and instead adopt the notion of snapshots of the current status of your code. A status is called branch. Git always starts with the branch `master`.

Taking up the example, starting with one `index.html` in your initial status, in branch `master`. Now you want to totally rewrite the file but to keep the original file because you are not sure yet which version is better.

This is why you will create a new branch. Let's call it `rework`. You can do so by the following command:

`git branch rework`

Switch to the new version, aka branch:

`git checkout rework`

Make your chances to `index.html` and save the file.

Switch back to your original environment with:

`git checkout master`

The content of `index.html` will the same as before creating the new version.

What this means is that git keeps versions of the very same file and writes them to your physical disk depending on which branch you are in.

You can even totally change your real folders content, such as deleting files with the following command - for the sake of the example only in the branch `rework`.

`git remove index.html`

When switching back to `master`, the file will be back again.

To sum it up:
Git manages the physical versions of your files, as long as you work with branches you can do to the files and folders whatever you want. You can switch back and forth between folders that look totally different on your hard drive, but are really only different branches in one git repository.

Answer (score 1):

Branches exactly help you managing those problems.
Creating a branch or not belongs to project policy or user preferences, but usually it's a good habit to start with a new branch when you have to do any change.

You can create the branch and check it out with

```
git checkout -b rework
```

That create a new branch named rework and switch to this say "new" environment.
Here you can modify and test your changes. Once you're happy with your changes you can either merge the rework branch in master.
You can create any number of branches with different changes.
You can only work with a branch at time. So any time you switch to a new branch you'll only have access to files of that branch.
To switch between branches, just use

```
git checkout rework
```

or

```
git checkout rework-1
```

or

```
git checkout master
```